# Unable to install miniconda3 on a mac

Tags: bash, anaconda, sh, miniconda

I am trying to install miniconda via the bash script from the official [source](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). I have followed all the official instructions as well as double checked with existing information for the installation of miniconda 3 via bash.

I keep getting this error about locale;

```
tar: Failed to set default locale
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: python-3.6.5-hc167b69_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
installing: ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: libcxxabi-4.0.1-hebd6815_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: tk-8.6.7-h35a86e2_3 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: xz-5.2.3-h727817e_4 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: yaml-0.1.7-hc338f04_2 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: zlib-1.2.11-hf3cbc9b_2 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: libcxx-4.0.1-h579ed51_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: openssl-1.0.2o-h26aff7b_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: libffi-3.2.1-h475c297_4 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: ncurses-6.0-hd04f020_2 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: libedit-3.1-hb4e282d_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: readline-7.0-hc1231fa_4 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: sqlite-3.23.1-hf1716c9_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: asn1crypto-0.24.0-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: certifi-2018.4.16-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: chardet-3.0.4-py36h96c241c_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: idna-2.6-py36h8628d0a_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: pycosat-0.6.3-py36hee92d8f_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: pycparser-2.18-py36h724b2fc_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: pysocks-1.6.8-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: python.app-2-py36_8 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: ruamel_yaml-0.15.35-py36h1de35cc_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: six-1.11.0-py36h0e22d5e_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: cffi-1.11.5-py36h342bebf_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: setuptools-39.0.1-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: cryptography-2.2.2-py36h1de35cc_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: wheel-0.31.0-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: pip-9.0.3-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: pyopenssl-17.5.0-py36h51e4350_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: urllib3-1.22-py36h68b9469_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: requests-2.18.4-py36h4516966_1 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installing: conda-4.5.1-py36_0 ...
tar: Failed to set default locale
installation finished.
```

My default locale is set to `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"` if that helps.

Here's my bash_profile content:

```
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"


export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Here's my locale settings:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

How do I fix this error and install miniconda3 on a mac? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have R installed? http://www.janosgyerik.com/fixing-r-error-in-mac-os-x-tar-failed-to-set-default-locale/

Comment: Yep. R and R studio installed

Comment: @darthbith run that in the terminal. Same errors

Comment: What is the output of `which tar`?

Comment: @darthbith __/usr/bin/tar__

Comment: "`installation finished.`" seems to suggest that the install completed. Did the installation not finish successfully?

Comment: also what is the exact command you are using to install Miniconda?

Comment: @user5359531installation can't be initialized. Using this guide to install: https://www.davidculley.com/installing-python-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the error could be here :

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#macos-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8
https://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/

FYI: I downloaded the Link on my Mac OS running Sierra  and ran 2.7 bash install with absolutely no issues.

```
$ cd Downloads
$ chmod a+x ./Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
$ ./Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh 

Welcome to Miniconda2 4.5.1

In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
agreement.
Please, press ENTER to continue
>>> 
===================================
Miniconda End User License Agreement
===================================

Copyright 2015, Anaconda, Inc.

>>> 
Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
>>> yes

Miniconda2 will now be installed into this location:
/Users/it/miniconda2

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/Users/it/miniconda2] >>> 
PREFIX=/Users/it/miniconda2
installing: python-2.7.14-h138c1fe_31 ...
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
installing: ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0 ...
installing: conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_0 ...
installing: libcxxabi-4.0.1-hebd6815_0 ...
installing: tk-8.6.7-h35a86e2_3 ...
installing: yaml-0.1.7-hc338f04_2 ...
installing: zlib-1.2.11-hf3cbc9b_2 ...
installing: libcxx-4.0.1-h579ed51_0 ...
installing: openssl-1.0.2o-h26aff7b_0 ...
installing: libffi-3.2.1-h475c297_4 ...
installing: ncurses-6.0-hd04f020_2 ...
installing: libedit-3.1-hb4e282d_0 ...
installing: readline-7.0-hc1231fa_4 ...
installing: sqlite-3.23.1-hf1716c9_0 ...
installing: asn1crypto-0.24.0-py27_0 ...
installing: certifi-2018.4.16-py27_0 ...
installing: chardet-3.0.4-py27h2842e91_1 ...
installing: enum34-1.1.6-py27hf475452_1 ...
installing: futures-3.2.0-py27h1b80678_0 ...
installing: idna-2.6-py27hedea723_1 ...
installing: ipaddress-1.0.22-py27_0 ...
installing: pycosat-0.6.3-py27h6c51c7e_0 ...
installing: pycparser-2.18-py27h0d28d88_1 ...
installing: pysocks-1.6.8-py27_0 ...
installing: python.app-2-py27hf2d5e94_7 ...
installing: ruamel_yaml-0.15.35-py27h1de35cc_1 ...
installing: six-1.11.0-py27h7252ba3_1 ...
installing: cffi-1.11.5-py27h342bebf_0 ...
installing: setuptools-39.0.1-py27_0 ...
installing: cryptography-2.2.2-py27h1de35cc_0 ...
installing: wheel-0.31.0-py27_0 ...
installing: pip-9.0.3-py27_0 ...
installing: pyopenssl-17.5.0-py27hfda213f_0 ...
installing: urllib3-1.22-py27hc3787e9_0 ...
installing: requests-2.18.4-py27h9b2b37c_1 ...
installing: conda-4.5.1-py27_0 ...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Miniconda2 install location
to PATH in your /Users/it/.bash_profile ? [yes|no]
[yes] >>> yes

Appending source /Users/it/miniconda2/bin/activate in
newly created /Users/it/.bash_profile

For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal.

Thank you for installing Miniconda2!
```

My locale settings:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I just set __export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"__ in my bash_profile and tried to install again. Same error :(

Comment: @Mysterio I posted all of mine, try setting all of those in the terminal. Type 'locale' to confirm what they are before / after etc. ..

Comment: it looks like only my lang is set to US.UTF-8. Added my locale to the question, in case, someone goes through the same thing. Going to change all values now.